# Can this grammar parse JSON object?

Tags: json, yacc, lex, context-free-grammar

Can this grammar parse JSON object?

```
d= { kvp }   
kvp= key : value  | key : value , kvp  
value= num | str | true | false  | array | d   | null
array= [] | [ element ]   
element= value | value , element
key= num | str
```

Comment: Good question. Put it into a lex/yacc program and test it out.

Comment: It can't match keywords like 'null', 'true', and 'false' which may be allowed in some versions of json.  It also requires a lexer that can recognize `num` and `str` as single tokens.  Other than that, it looks fine, though is right recursive so is more suitable for a top-down tool like ANTLR rather than a bottom up tool like yacc/bison as they prefer left recursion.

Comment: @chrisDodd: I don't believe there is (or has ever been) any JSON profile which does not include `null`, `true`, `false` or empty objects. (Although RFC 7493 recommends that named values, strings and numbers not be used as *top-level* messages, because the now-obsoleted RFC 4627 insisted that top-level constructs be objects or arrays.)

Comment: Since parsing performance is of the essence, I'd be surprised if any approach built on a parser generator could beat a hand-crafted parser.

Comment: @torazaburo (a) Parsing performance is not of the essence where JSON is concerned. Network performance is of the essence. (B) Generated parsers are fully competitive with handwritten parsers and have been for about fifty years.

Comment: In addition to other comments, this grammar does not allow the empty object `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good but as Chris mentioned in the comments said, all JSON profiles usually contain `null, true, false ...` which are missing here.

Check out this grammar(taken from json.org):

> json    : value    ;
>
> obj    : '{' pair (',' pair)* '}'    | '{' '}'    ;
>
> pair    : STRING ':' value    ;
>
> array    : '[' value (',' value)* ']'    | '[' ']'    ;
>
> value    : STRING    | NUMBER    | obj    | array    | 'true'    |
> 'false'    | 'null'    ;
>
> STRING    : '"' (ESC | SAFECODEPOINT)* '"'    ;
>
> fragment ESC    : '\' (["\/bfnrt] | UNICODE)    ;
>
> fragment UNICODE    : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX    ;
>
> fragment HEX    : [0-9a-fA-F]    ;
>
> fragment SAFECODEPOINT    : ~ ["\\u0000-\u001F]    ;
>
> NUMBER    : '-'? INT ('.' [0-9] +)? EXP?    ;
>
> fragment INT    : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*    ;
>
> // no leading zeros
>
> fragment EXP    : [Ee] [+-]? INT    ;
>
> // - since - means "range" inside [...]
>
> WS    : [ \t\n\r] + -> skip    ;